# Express routing non ascii characters (Farsi)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, non-ascii-characters, unicode-string

I am trying to use this route [http://localhost:3030/api/words/عشق](http://localhost:3030/api/words/%D8%B9%D8%B4%D9%82)
in my express app, so I can match the word in the dictionary.

The browser changes the url to http://localhost:3030/api/words/%D8%B9%D8%B4%D9%82 but I have written a small middleware that converts it back to the original version before passing it in to the routes. In the routes, I have the regex that checks for unicode character that encompasses farsi/persian characters.

Not sure what's going on because the middleware prints `/words/عشق` and if I remove the regex rule the route also prints `/words/عشق`. Why is express not matching this ? Does express not use the req.url to determine the route ?

```
    /** Get word be string **/
    api.get('/:word(^([\\u0600-\\u06FF]+\\s?)+$)', (req, res, next) =>{
            console.log("persian version " + req.url);
            res.send(req.params);
});


 /** Url encoder middleware **/ 
function urlencoder(req, res, next) {
      req.url = decodeURIComponent(req.url); 
      console.log("Middleware " + req.url);
      next();
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't use it.  It also feels wrong to rewrite it like that.  Why not just decode it in your `api.get` function before looking it up?

Comment: Because I can't use the regex to match the url if it is not pre-decoded.

Comment: It should actually work to modify req.url - from my reading of what Express routers actually do.  What's the definition of api and where are api and urlencoder in the middleware stack?

Comment: Yes, it definitely does work to use middleware to adjust the value of req.url - all routes after that point in the middleware chain are routing based on the modified URL.

Comment: I am adding the middleware after the cors middleware and before the body parser. Even turned off the other middlewares but doesn't seem to work. The api is an express router to group the routes in a different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code that converts the route path to a regular expression already prefixes the regex with an anchor (`^`), so you shouldn't use an additional one in yours.

This seems to work:

```
let unescape = require('querystring').unescape;

api.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.url = unescape(req.url);
  next();
});

api.get('/:word(([\\u0600-\\u06FF]+\\s?)+$)', (req, res) => {
  console.log("persian version " + req.url);
  res.send(req.params);
});
```

Comment: I don't think the router prefix the regexp with `^` automatically but rather I think it is a misunderstanding of what `^` means. `^` means "string starts with" or "line starts with" depending on the multiline flag. So searching for a string where the beginning of that string is in the middle will not match any possible string (note that URLs are by definition a single line so there can only be one interpretation of what `^` means)

Comment: @slebetman I think we mean the same :D A route path like `/:word` will be converted to a regexp that starts with `^\/` (followed by a match for a parameter). Therefore, adding another `^` will never be able to match the start of the path.

Comment: @robertklep No, we don't mean the same. His regexp is ':word^...' - he's trying to match a string that starts after any alphanumeric character. Which obviously will never match any string because the definition of "starts" means that there cannot be anything before it. It's like someone trying to match the regexp '.*$hello' -- a string that ends before it ends is as silly as a string that starts after it starts

Comment: @slebetman `:word` isn't a literal string to match in the URL, it's a placeholder that gets translated to a particular regex pattern (matching a sequence of alnum chars, I think) by Express. You can override which pattern to match for that placeholder by adding your own regex pattern, using `:word(REGEX)`

Comment: @robertklep: Yes, but `^` is also not a literal string match. And it means "no character before this character" - otherwise known as "start of string". So if :word matches something then following it with `^` means that `^` can no longer be the start of string therefore the regex matches no possible string. The only possible way that the original regex can work is if `:word` means the empty string but that's not what it normally means. I have assumed it to mean any alphanumeric character instead of an empty string (as I said in my comment above)

Comment: @slebetman we're still both right: you because it doesn't make sense to anchor the start of the string when there's already a prefix to match, and me because it also doesn't make sense to have two `^` anchors in a regex.